# How to prove the decision version of the bin packing problem is NP?

Tags: algorithm, np, bin-packing

I've seen some [sources](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/) online that indicate that you can find the lower bound on the minimum number of bins. However, how can one use this to definitely know whether a set of objects with known weights will fit into *k* boxes? You can check if *k* is less than the lower bound and this will tell you if the objects *cannot* fit into the box, but if *k* is equal to or greater than the lower bound wouldn't it still be possible for the objects not to all fit? Or is this not the complete description of the decision problem?

Another [source](https://cs.ubishops.ca/home/cs567/more-np-complete/rangasamy-bin-packing.pdf)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about the theory of computation, not computer programming.

Comment: Algorithms either compute is the optimum or an *upper bound* on the minimum number of bins (approximation). This is not a *proof* of the problem being in NP which asks for rigorous derivation. If you are comfortable with PARTITION being NP complete, the same [follows suit for BinP](https://ac.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/lak_teaching/ws11_12/combopt/notes/bin_packing.pdf). The decision problem is phrased as whether you can allot the given number of objects with given weights into `k` bins or less. While you would not know whether `k-1` bins suffice, you are guaranteed that `k` bins are enough.